# Löwenheim–Skolem theorem without parameters?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

On page 160 of Smullyan's "A Beginner's Guide to Mathematical Logic",  the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem and the compactness theorem is stated and proved in the following manner:

> **Theorem L.S.C.** If $S$ is a set of closed formulas without parameters, and all finite subsets of $S$ are satisfiable, then the entire set $S$ is satisfiable in a denumerable domain.
>
> **Proof.** We are given a denumerable set $S$ of closed formulas without parameters such that all finite subsets of $S$ are satisfiable. As in the case of Propositional Logic, we arrange the elements of $S$ in some denumerable sequence $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n,\ldots$. We start the tableau with $X_1$ at the origin. This concludes the first stage, and at any stage $n$, we proceed systematically, as already explained, and also append $X_{n+1}$ at the end of every open branch. Since every finite subset of $S$ is satisfiable, then at no stage can the tableau close. Hence it has an infinite open branch $\theta$, and the set of formulas on $\theta$ is a Hintikka set (since the construction is systematic), and contains all the elements of $S$. Thus $S$ is satisfiable in the denumerable domain of the parameters.

I believe that this proof is quite straightforward, since constructing the tableau is very mechanical. What I don't understand here is: **why is the theorem stated only for closed formulas without parameters?** Does the same method of proof fails when some elements of $S$ has parameters in them (If this is the case, please enlighten me)? Why is it necessary to distinguish the L.S.C. theorem in two different versions - with/without parameters?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't have the book with me at the moment, but if I recall correctly a Hintikka set is defined as a set of closed formulas; so as stated, the construction wouldn't literally produce a Hintikka set. We could modify the definition of Hintikka set to accomodate free variables, but that would produce minor nuisances elsewhere if memory serves. Meanwhile, I'm a bit confused. Without a specific structure in mind, I don't know what "parameter" means; so everywhere I see "parameter" above, I'm wondering why I don't see "free variable" instead.  (cont'd)

Comment: And indeed the "structural" version of Lowenheim-Skolem - that whenever $A\subseteq\mathfrak{S}$ is a subset of an infinite structure, there is some $\mathfrak{A}$ of cardinality $\vert A\vert\cdot\aleph_0$ with $A\subseteq\mathfrak{A}\preccurlyeq\mathfrak{S}$ - does not appear to follow from the argument given above (which is why I dislike that argument, at least when mentioned in the same sentence as the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem - it is much more satisfying as far as compactness is concerned).

Comment: Can you say what you would imagine the statement "with parameters" would be?  As stated, it doesn't really make sense to allow parameters, since they would need to take value in some structure but the theorem is just a statement about formulas without reference to any fixed structure.  As Noah commented, there are related theorems that allow parameters, but they are formulated differently.